# Webpack compression fails on spread operator in objects on CircleCI

Tags: javascript, webpack, circleci

I compressed my bundle and was able to serve up `webpack-bundled.js.gz`, the gzip version of the bundle. Everything works perfectly in localhost and in a test environment, but my code keeps failing on CircleCI with a weird message. It seems that CircleCI doesn't recognize spread operator.

Here is the error message:

```
/home/circleci/shine/node_modules/compression-webpack-plugin/node_modules/find-up/index.js:29
        const foundPath = await runMatcher({...options, cwd: directory});
                                            ^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token ...
    at NativeCompileCache._moduleCompile (/home/circleci/shine/node_modules/v8-compile-cache/v8-compile-cache.js:226:18)
    at Module._compile (/home/circleci/shine/node_modules/v8-compile-cache/v8-compile-cache.js:172:36)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:488:32)
    at ...
    ....
```

I tried to move `compression-webpack-plugin` from devDependencies to dependencies, but it still doesn't work.

This is my `webpack.config.js`.

```
const config = {
  "entry": {
    "webpack-bundle": "./app/registration",
  },

  "output": {
    filename: "[name].js",
    path: pathLib.resolve(__dirname, "../app/assets/webpack"),
  },

  "module": {
    "rules": [
      {
        "exclude": /node_modules/,
        "test": /\.jsx?$/,
        "use": {
          "loader": "babel-loader",
          "options": {
            "plugins": [
              "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties",
              ["@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators", {"legacy": true}],
              "@babel/plugin-proposal-export-namespace-from",
              "@babel/plugin-proposal-function-sent",
              "@babel/plugin-proposal-json-strings",
              "@babel/plugin-proposal-numeric-separator",
              "@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread",
              "@babel/plugin-proposal-throw-expressions",
              "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import",
              "@babel/plugin-syntax-import-meta",
              "@babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx"
            ],
            "presets": [
              "@babel/preset-env",
              "@babel/preset-react"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    ],
  },

  "plugins": [
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      "$": "jquery",
      "jQuery": "jquery",
      "window.jQuery": "jquery"
    }),
    new UglifyJsPlugin(),
    new CompressionPlugin({
      "filename": "[path].gz[query]",
      "test": /\.js$|\.css$|\.html$/,
      "algorithm": "gzip",
      "threshold": 10240,
      "minRatio": 0.8
    })
  ],

  "resolve": {
    "alias": {
      "Lib": pathLib.resolve(__dirname, "app/lib/"),
      "Shared": pathLib.resolve(__dirname, "app/shared/")
    },
    "extensions": [".js", ".jsx"]
  }
};

module.exports = config;
```

Since I have no issue creating and serving the gzipped webpack bundle locally and in a test environment, I expect them to work in CircleCI. I am not sure if this is a dependency issue (seems unlikely) or a setting I need to change on CircleCI.

Another related question: can I add `compression-webpack-plugin` in dependencies, or is it strictly a plugin for development? [The office documentation](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/compression-webpack-plugin/) uses `--save-dev`, so that's what I did initially. But even after I moved this plug in to dependency, nothing changed. Any thoughts?

Comment: https://github.com/babel/babel-loader/issues/170 could be helpful?

Comment: What nodejs version are you using locally? What nodejs version is CircleCI running? You might be running into an issue with differing nodejs versions. Sometimes the CI will run a different version than you have locally and cause different behaviors.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Thank you! I tried a few plugins like `@babel/plugin-transform-destructuring` and `babel-plugin-transform-es2015-destructuring` but I am still getting the same error from CircleCI.

Comment: @Kyle My nodejs version locally is v10.15.3, our nodejs on CircleCI is `circleci/ruby:2.3.3-node-browsers`. This is a pre-built docker image, but I am sure which nodejs version it corresponds to, but it could be v10.8. https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/circleci-images/

Comment: "CircleCI doesn't recognize spread operator" - to be clear, it would be Node that does (or does not) recognise JavaScript operators. Perhaps you have installed the wrong version of Node? Remember that CI servers are basically just Linux machines, and Circle/Jenkins/Travis/GitLab are generally not doing anything to stop it working.

Comment: CircleCI offer a post-SSH session feature, so if you are stuck, you could get an SSH session and play around (install things, uninstall things, run and re-run tests, get version info). This is often faster than pushing code and waiting for a whole test suite to finish.

Comment: Ah, I see in a comment you've said you don't know what version of Node you have in CircleCI. Getting an SSH session to confirm that would be a good first step. As a longer term plan, I would also recommend using Docker to ensure that the version of Node you are using is consistent over as many of your envs as possible (local, CI, staging, maybe even prod).